# Does Laravel 4 have an event for when a user is logged on via cookie?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to keep track of every time a user logs on to my site. I can handle the auth.login event just fine, but when a user is logged in via their "Remember Me" cookie, the event does not fire. What is the best way to handle that?

Comment: They are not "logged in" via the cookie - they *stay* logged in.

Comment: Can you show some code for how you're currently logging users in, or checking if they've already logged in?

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific event for this, but there are methods to help you create one.

**Put this in your `app/start/global.php`:** (or create a new `app/events.php` and include it in `app/start/global.php`)

You could put your `auth.cookieLogin` logic in the `auth.login` listener if you never see yourself wanting to fire it independently.

```
// An additional login listener to the one found at /Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    if(Auth::viaRemember())
    {
        $event = Event::fire('auth.cookieLogin', array($user));
    }
    // don't return false here unless you want to stop propagation of the other auth.login event listener.
});

Event::listen('auth.cookieLogin', function($user)
{
    // do something and/or return something.
});
```

Comment: This looks promising.  Where would I put the first part.  Ideally, I don't want to check this on every page load, I just want to check it one time, when the Auth::user() session variable is created.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I can't get auth.cookieLogin to fire.  It never seems to match the if(Auth::viaRemember()) condition.  I tried closing my browser and coming back an hour later, and it never fired.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm.   Looking into this more, there seems to have been some confusion amongst others as to what `Auth::viaRemember()` actually does.  Check out these questions and [this specific comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3318#issuecomment-50289104) about setting `expire_on_close` = `true`.  Also, if that doesn't help, try replacing `if(Auth::viaRemember())` with `if(Auth::check() && Auth::viaRemember())`

Comment: I also tried setting /app/config/session.php lifetime=1, expire_on_close=true, closing the browser and reopening after a couple minute.  After that didn't work, I deleted all session files at /app/storage/sessions, restarted browser, still no luck.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help, but I've tried that page as well, to no luck.  I didn't try Auth::check() at the time of my previous comment, but I just tried it now unsuccessfully.